can i trust these php codes and build my site based on them and feel relax?
my question is not how to detect mobile device .
i am asking about trusting . i already put a code that detect mobile in my post , so i dont ask how to , i ask can i trust them or not for site that will have a lot of users .
// Check if the "mobile" word exists in User-Agent
$isMob = is_numeric(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]), "mobile")); 

My question is:
Can I build a website based on such code without any worries?.
The point of the question is whether these codes are permanent, stable and work professionally in detecting devices.

"i am asking about trusting" - what do you mean by "trusting"? Whom do you want to trust by that? The code you've shared is permanent, it won't change in any way, in the same way as any other code you write won't change unless you change it
